# Node post date in views exposed filter as a select list

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I want to add a node post date exposed filter to the views in the following format.

The date exposed filter will be a select list with the following options:

```
All
Today
Yesterday
Past Week
Past Month
Past Year
```

It it possible with views or I have to do some workaround?

No one has an answer for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with the following steps.

Added a post date exposed filter, with option `Grouped filter` instead of `single filter`.

Widget type `Select`. With the following options in the table

```
  Label        Operator                       Value

  Today        is greater than or equal to    today

  Yesterday    is greater than or equal to    -1 day

  Past week    is greater than or equal to    -1 week

  Past month   is greater than or equal to    -1 month

  Past year    is greater than or equal to    -1 year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Views, dealing with **Combined** **filters.** Try it with option **Grouped**.